# Does Facebook SDK support Swift 2.3/3.0?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Ok, I can't figure out what's the catch here. I follow all [the instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/getting-started) to configure my new project using CocoaPods to use Facebook SDK. Once I open generated project workspace, Xcode offers me to convert some source code in Pods project to Swift 2.3 or Swift 3.0.

I tried twice - with converting to Swift 3.0 and converting to Swift 2.3. Neither works and both give me on average ~120 compilation-time errors.
What's the deal here? I can't find anyone with similar problems. [They seem to support Swift 2.3](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2016/07/14/swift-sdk-beta/), but it doesn't work actually.

Xcode 8.0, Deployment target 8.0, latest FB sdk available through pods - 4.16.1

Comment: Yes it supports Swift 3. Here is tutorial for [Facebook Login with Swift 3](http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/05/facebook-login-swift-language-ios/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook version [0.2.0](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/releases/tag/0.2.0) has support for Swift 3.0. Make sure you do the following before installing the latest version of Facebook SDK:

1: Get the latest version of Cocapods:

```
gem install cocoapods
(or if the above fails)
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

2: Update your local specs repo by running:

```
pod repo update
```

3: And then update your pod file and run `pod update` or `pod install`

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
```

I think your probably missing step 1.

Comment: Np, glad to help @peetonn

Comment: @RashwanL do you have any idea as to what FBSDK version supports Swift 2.3?

Comment: @Zonily Jame  for swift 2.3 go for FacebookShare version 0.1.1 

pod 'FacebookCore', '~> 0.1.1'
pod 'FacebookLogin', '~> 0.1.1'
pod 'FacebookShare', '~> 0.1.1'

Comment: used it, there are bugs. used FBSDK (objective c) and just bridged to swift instead